# VBA: How to Read SharePoint Properties (DocumentTypeProperties) for Visio Files?

Tags: vba, sharepoint, properties, metadata, visio

I'm trying to read the SharePoint properties (like version) for a Visio file, in a SharePoint document library.

In Word, Excel and PowerPoint you can read SharePoint properties with VBA via the property “.DocumentTypeProperties” for ActiveDocument (Word), Workbook  (Excel) or ActivePresentation (Powerpoint). Example for PowerPoint that displays a Messagebox with all SharePoint Properties:

```
Option Explicit

Sub printContentTypeProperties()
    Dim prop As Variant
    Dim propstr$
    propstr$ = ""
    For Each prop In ActivePresentation.ContentTypeProperties
        Select Case VarType(prop.Value)
        Case 8: ' String
            propstr$ = propstr$ & prop.Name & ": " & prop.Value & Chr$(10)
        Case 2 To 6 Or 14 Or 17 Or 20: ' Number (numeric value)
            propstr$ = propstr$ & prop.Name & ": " & Str$(prop.Value) & Chr$(10)
        Case Else:
            propstr$ = propstr$ & prop.Name & ": " & "NO_STRING_OR_NUMBER" & Chr$(10)
        End Select
    Next prop
    MsgBox propstr$
End Sub
```

I really have searched on Google, StackOverflow for a long time, but I cannot find how to read SharePoint properties for Visio files. The “Document” object of Visio (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/visio.document) does not have a property “DocumentTypeProperties”.

Is it possible to read the SharePoint properties with VBA for Visio files? Which Visio version is necessary (Standard or Professional)?

Comment: Seems related to this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/visio-2016-document-properties-in-sharepoint/aea1d1ec-3af9-4909-aa5a-532f46dac2f8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to read (user-defined) Visio file SharePoint properties from a Visio file.

You can always parse Visio file yourself though. If those properties exist in the file, you'll be able to fetch them, as Visio file now is just a bunch of zipped xml files (assuming that the file is not in the old binary format)

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, I will try to parse the xml files myself.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIk there is no `DocumentTypeProperties`, but you can access the standard ones directly from the `document` object.   [MSDN Discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/85fbc601-1612-4e63-91f4-b900a59109bd/how-to-access-visio-document-properties-builtindocumentproperties-amp-customdocumentproperties?forum=visiogeneral)

```
ThisDocument.FullName
ThisDocument.TimeCreated
ThisDocument.Creator
```

If you want to save some Information inside your Document you can save them in the Shapsheet of the Document `ThisDocument.DocumentSheet`, I have not found a better option so far.